# Can I get a notification of failed WiFi connection for secured network?

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, security, htc-hero, 2.1-eclair

I have an HTC Hero running Android 2.1. My work has a secured wifi network that we're allowed to connect our phones too. We also have to change our account passwords every so often. When this happens, my credentials are incorrect when trying to connect to the wifi from my phone. But the phone doesn't tell me that, it just keeps trying, which ends up locking my account because of failed logins. Is there a way to get the WiFi app to notify me when the connection fails so I can update the credentials, rather than continuing to try to connect, locking out my account?

Answer (score 4):

The best way I know is to use an app called [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Its price is a little steeper than most, but it's very useful once you start playing with it. Check out lifehacker to see some other examples of what Tasker can do.

Here are the steps for what you want to do:

1. Open Tasker
2. Select "New"
3. Name it "wifi alert" (or whatever)
4. Select "OK"
5. Select "State"
6. Select "Wifi Connected"
7. Enter the SSID for your network
8. Make sure the "Invert" check box is checked
9. Select "Done"
10. Select "New Task"
11. Name it "disconnect" (or whatever)
12. Select "OK"
13. Select the "+" icon
14. Select "Alert"
15. Select "Popup"
16. Enter some text (wifi disconnected or something more ominous)
17. Select "Done"
18. Select "Done"
19. Select "Apply"

You could also make your phone vibrate or play a sound if you prefer. If you're worried you won't see/hear the notification in your pocket, you can also automatically disable wifi until you have the correct credentials. Just add another action to the task by going to "Net", selecting "WiFi" and setting it to "Off".

Tasker is great fun to nerd out on and isn't nearly as complicated as my numbered list might imply.

Comment: I'll definitely look into this. Bummer that it costs money though :(