# How to spawn "sign-in to network" page for a captive portal?

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, settings, 5.1-lollipop, networking

How do I execute [captive portal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/CaptivePortal)?

On a [Z828](https://www.ztedevices.ca/catalog/product/view/id/29/s/z828/category/21/) from ZTE, Android version 5.1.1, I'm [trying](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6183600?hl=en) to get something like:

[image: IMG:]

While Starbucks generally works for me, all too often, other networks, when using public Wi-Fi, simply give a notice along the lines of:

[image: IMG:]

See also:

[Can I get a notification of failed WiFi connection for secured network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/can-i-get-a-notification-of-failed-wifi-connection-for-secured-network)

[Notify when connected to working Wi-Fi point](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/notify-when-connected-to-working-wi-fi-point)

[Only connect to certain Wi-Fi networks](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32963/only-connect-to-certain-wi-fi-networks)

[Nearby wifi networks causing notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168647/nearby-wifi-networks-causing-notification)

[How to disable the "sign in to wifi network" page?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186324/how-to-disable-the-sign-in-to-wifi-network-page)

Although nothing is quite on point, leaving me [at](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6183600?hl=en):

> Still can't connect?
>
> If you still can't connect, please contact your Internet Service
>   Provider, router manufacturer, or network administrator.

Which, simply isn't an option for most public Wi-Fi hotspots.  [Perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23775002/262852), there's simply no solution.

Incidentally, my Kindle connects to the Wi-Fi hotspot, then, of its own volition, brings me to the captive portal through datavalet.  Seems specific to Android that I must first try to browse to a random website, which, sometimes, will then bring me to a captive portal.  Maybe.

Comment: no solution, but probably the same problem here:  [My android can't log in to Wifi networks with Captive Portals](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/101481/48164)

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the firewall vendor and how they implement it. If you're using a Cisco, such as one of the Meraki devices- the captive portal spawns best under Firefox versus Chrome/ium or Opera. And also another way to catch it, is to

- Disconnect from the access point
- Clear any saved credentials
- Re-log in

Take care to notice the notifications you're likely to get a prompt. Follow the prompts. If your AP is as I have mine set up, it is likely a click through the walled garden, these pages include a check box radio form entry field, You need to fill in the check, then click 'continue'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not get the splash screen to appear, this will bring the login page to your browser: http://httpforever.com

Comment: Explanation: Android needs to intercept the connection, but it's impossible if the site is HTTPS. Thus, any HTTP-only sites might help.